# What does it mean when $f(a)$ is defined?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I am in Calculus I and my calculus jargon is lacking so please if you can explain, for lack of better terms, explain it simply.

Comment: Roughly, it means that you encounter no problems when you plug $a$ into $f(x)$. For example, if $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{x-2}}$, then $f(3)$ is defined, but $f(2)$ is not because calculating $f(2)$ requires division by zero, and $f(1)$ is not defined because it requires taking the square root of a negative number.

Comment: so would f(4) be defined? Or does it have to be a whole number?

Comment: Yep! $f(x)$ is defined for all $x> 2$, and undefined for all $x\le 2$.

Comment: If there is a graph at a hole is f(a) defined?

Comment: Yeah, if the graph has a hole, then it is undefined where the hole is. An example is $f(x)=(x^2-1)/(x-1)$, which has a hole at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To broaden the scope a bit;

Usually functions are defined from a domain to a codomain.

If the function, $f$, takes values from a set $X$ and ends up in a set $Y$ we write that $f: X \to Y$.

We say that $f$ is well defined on $X$ when $f(a)$ is uniquely given in $Y$ (that is, it takes on exactly one value for $a$).

Now, given a well defined function $f: X \to Y$, to say that $f(a)$ is defined is to say that $a \in X$ and nothing more.

Hope this clarifies some things.

Answer (score 1):

"$f(a)$ is defined" means $f$ is a function, and $a$ is in the domain of $f$

For example suppose $f(x) = \frac 1x$

$f(1)$ is defined.
$f(0)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about a function, we really should always remember to include in our description of the function the **Domain** (*the set of all inputs we wish to consider*), the **Codomain** (*the set to which we are mapping, which may or may not include all outputs we actually can get*) and the actual rule we follow to map an input to an output.

The function $f$ with domain $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ and codomain $\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is properly defined for all nonzero real numbers $x$.  $f(0)$ however is not defined (*division by zero is not defined for real numbers*).

To be pedantic, I would argue that the function $g$ with domain $\{1,2,3\}$ and codomain $\{1\}$ given by $g(x)=1$ is defined for each of $\{1,2,3\}$.  Despite the rule $g(x)=1$ being easy to interpret for any and every input $x$, I would argue that $g$ is **not** defined for any value different from $1,2,3$.  $g(4)$ is not defined in this case.  Our definition of the function only told us what happens for inputs from $\{1,2,3\}$ and did *not* tell us anything about how $g$ "should" act on inputs outside of that.

Such functions can be *extended* to have a larger domain, but this would no longer be the same function strictly speaking.

Comment: I don’t think you were being pedantic at all. But then I’m a certified pedant.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of function, given $f:A\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ we say that  $\forall a\in A \quad f(a)$ is defined when

$$\exists!b\in B : \quad b=f(a)$$